# MSE conformance test for cobalt browser without VP9 support

Tags: cobalt

From a quick analysis of the qual-e mse conformance tests it seems to me that it is assumed that the platform supports VP9.

For example the test case for MSE AddSourceBuffer

```
var testAddSourceBuffer = createConformanceTest('AddSourceBuffer', 'MSE Core');
testAddSourceBuffer.prototype.title =
    'Test if we can add source buffer';
testAddSourceBuffer.prototype.onsourceopen = function() {
  try {
    this.runner.checkEq(this.ms.sourceBuffers.length, 0, 'Source buffer number');
    this.ms.addSourceBuffer(Media.AAC.mimetype);
    this.runner.checkEq(this.ms.sourceBuffers.length, 1, 'Source buffer number');
    this.ms.addSourceBuffer(Media.VP9.mimetype);
    this.runner.checkEq(this.ms.sourceBuffers.length, 2, 'Source buffer number');
  } catch (e) {
    this.runner.fail(e);
  }
  this.runner.succeed();
};
```

From my understanding this test will fail if browser does not support VP9. Is my understanding correct?
I understand that VP9 is generally required for 2017 and 2018 certification. 
Will it be possible to have a test page for a preliminary test for browsers that only currently support AVC?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. We will take this proposal into consideration.

FYI, VP9 has not been optional since 2016 year certification. Cobalt 11 has software VP9 implementation so that you can reuse that for the preliminary tests.